# optimal number of divisors for powers of 2

Tags: power-series, divisibility

I am running an experiment where i need to calculate the value close to a power of 2 that results in the largest number of divisors.   Specifically i am testing values in the range of 1% less than the value of the power of 2.  I have found the following relationship for values $2^n$

```
n   l
9   510
10  1020
11  2040
12  4080
13  8190
14  16380
15  32760
16  65520
17  131040
```

where $l$ is the value close to the value of the power of 2 that yields the greatest number of divisors.   There seems to be a pattern.  Is anyone aware of some theory that might explain this?

Comment: What is the "obvious pattern"? The answer for $n=13$ is not twice the answer for $n=12$. In general, it should be highly unlikely that the answers are simply doubling forever past any stage: in a long run of integers, it is very likely (and probably has been proved) that there will be a number with an abnormally large number of divisors.

Comment: You are right, I misspoke when I said "obvious."  I have edited accordingly

Comment: And what is the "non obvious" pattern (other than "within $1\%$ of a power of $2$") ?

Comment: differences go 2,4,8,16,2,4,8,16,32, but I figure it doesn't always work out.

Answer (score 1):

Having a large number of divisors and being close to a power of $2$ are conflicting objectives so that an "optimal number" seems elusive. You chose an arbitrary limit of $1\%$ which I doubt makes things simpler. IMO, the irregularity of the function $\sigma(n)$, which resists to analysis, makes your question too difficult.